# static Pay Pal link with business email and without default currency and amount

Tags: pdf, paypal

My client wants create pdf file with payment link for donation.
I inserted this file link.
`<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=myclient@gmail.com&cmd=_xclick&item_name=myclient@gmail.com">myclient@gmail.com</a>`.

The link works OK, but paypal opens with default amount 1 (but possibility to enter price) and default currency USD.
The client wants open paypal link with possibility to select any currency from currencies list and enter any amount.
I found in google only possibility create form with currencies and amount on Web page and send this
info to paypal, but I have no Web Page, I have static Pdf file.
Is it possible create static PayPal link, that opens paypal with possibility to select currency and to enter amount (without price) ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, the link should specify the currency and will default to USD if unspecified. Create several links if you need options for different currencies.

For donations you can use cmd=_donations

- https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=placeholderclient@email.com&currency_code=USD
- https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=placeholderclient@email.com&currency_code=EUR